# BeautifulSoup find_all by table and id class returning no results?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape box-score data from ProFootball reference. After running into issues with javascript, I turned to selenium to get the initial soup object. I'm trying to find a specific table on a website and subsequently iterate through its rows.

The code words if I simply find_all('table')[#] however the # changes depending on which box score I am looking at so it isn't reliable. I therefore want to use the id='player_offense' tag to identify the same table across games but when I use it it returns nothing. What am I missing here?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

#path to chromedriver
chrome_path=os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/chromedriver.exe') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get('https://www.pro-football- 
reference.com/boxscores/201709070nwe.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
driver.quit()

#doesn't work
soup.find('table',id='player_offense')
#works
table = soup.find_all('table')[3]
```

Comment: Is soup.table even a valid attribute?

Comment: Did you try `soup.find('table', id='player_offense')`?

Comment: `soup.find('table', id='player_offense')` instead of `soup.table.find('table',id='player_offense')` wrong

Comment: Hi, apologies, I was searching soup.find('table',id='player_offense'). I must have changed the code and forgotten to change back. Edit made to questions=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is in comments. Find the appropriate comment and then extract table

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from bs4 import Comment
import pandas as pd

r= requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201709070nwe.htm#')
soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))

for comment in comments:
    if 'id="player_offense"' in comment:
        print(pd.read_html(comment)[0])
        break
```

Comment: thank you! I knew it was in the comments but I thought that had something to do with the JavaScript. Glad to know I don't need selenium

Comment: you don't really need pandas either but it is nice for quick formatted table extraction.

Answer (score 0):

This also works.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession, HTML
import pandas as pd

with HTMLSession() as s:

    r = s.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201709070nwe.htm')

    r = HTML(html=r.text)
    r.render()
    table = r.find('table#player_offense', first=True)
    df = pd.read_html(table.html)
    print(df)
```